# Errors starting frontend on angular project visual studio code

Tags: node.js, angular

I got this error when I just download and npm/install/run  this angular based project.
https://github.com/OpenClassrooms-Student-Center/dwj-projet6

Instructions :

- Clone project
- Execute npm install
- Execute npm start.
- API execution on http://localhost:3000

### Errors

> ng serve
> Your global Angular CLI version (11.2.6) is greater than your local version (7.0.7). The local Angular CLI version is used.

> To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".
> Schema validation failed with the following errors:
>   Data path ".builders['app-shell']" should have required property 'class'.
> Error: Schema validation failed with the following errors:
>   Data path ".builders['app-shell']" should have required property 'class'.
>     at MergeMapSubscriber.project (C:\Users\Phil\Desktop\Beta\dwj-projet6\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\workspace\workspace.js:215:42)
>     at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (C:\Users\Phil\Desktop\Beta\dwj-projet6\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:69:27)
>     at MergeMapSubscriber._next (C:\Users\Phil\Desktop\Beta\dwj-projet6\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:59:18)
>     at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\Users\Phil\Desktop\Beta\dwj-projet6\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:67:18)
>     at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (C:\Users\Phil\Desktop\Beta\dwj-projet6\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:92:26)
>     at InnerSubscriber._next (C:\Users\Phil\Desktop\Beta\dwj-projet6\node_modules\rxjs\internal\InnerSubscriber.js:28:21)
>     at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\Users\Phil\Desktop\Beta\dwj-projet6\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:67:18)
>     at MapSubscriber._next (C:\Users\Phil\Desktop\Beta\dwj-projet6\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\map.js:55:26)
>     at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\Users\Phil\Desktop\Beta\dwj-projet6\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:67:18)
>     at SwitchMapSubscriber.notifyNext (C:\Users\Phil\Desktop\Beta\dwj-projet6\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\switchMap.js:86:26)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's works fine for me.

**Try below way maybe it help you**

Solution 1: Delete node_modules folder and run npm install.

Solution 2: I think you should decrease your angular CLI version, try with CLI **version 8**.

Comment: Hi, what about security vulnerabilities ? isn't it better to update the project?

Comment: Yes your project is in angular V7.0.7, so you need to appropriate version of CLI